# Loop Powershell script to re-prompt user ever hour or until timeout limit is reached

Tags: powershell, sccm, reboot

Newbie

I would like to use a Powershell script similar to example below to prompt endusers with the toast message that a reboot is required, then present a message box to restart now or select no to delay. If no is selected, I would like the script to wait an hour and prompt the user again every hour until the timeout period is reached. For example start the prompts at 7:00am local machine time, then prompt every hour with the option to reboot now by selecting yes or defer by selecting no until 1:oopm local machine time. Then user the machine will reboot in 10 min. to save work.

I will deploy this using SCCM. This would be run once per week.

Script ex.

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") | out-null
$TimeStart = Get-Date
$TimeEnd = $timeStart.addminutes(360)
Do
{
    $TimeNow = Get-Date
    if ($TimeNow -ge $TimeEnd)
    {
        
        Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier click_event -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        Remove-Event click_event -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
        [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
        Exit
    }
    else
    {
        $Balloon = new-object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
        $Balloon.Icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information
        $Balloon.BalloonTipText = "IT is requiring a reboot in order to maintain system stability supporting IT security measures. Please reboot at your earliest convenience."
        $Balloon.BalloonTipTitle = "Reboot Required"
        $Balloon.BalloonTipIcon = "Warning"
        $Balloon.Visible = $true;
        $Balloon.ShowBalloonTip(20000);
        $Balloon_MouseOver = [System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler]{ $Balloon.ShowBalloonTip(20000) }
        $Balloon.add_MouseClick($Balloon_MouseOver)
        Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier click_event -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        Register-ObjectEvent $Balloon BalloonTipClicked -sourceIdentifier click_event -Action {
            Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
            
            If ([Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::MsgBox('Would you like to reboot your machine now?', 'YesNo,MsgBoxSetForeground,Question', 'System Maintenance') -eq "NO")
            { }
            else
            {
                shutdown -r -f
            }
            
        } | Out-Null
        
        Wait-Event -timeout 3600 -sourceIdentifier click_event > $null
        Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier click_event -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $Balloon.Dispose()
    }

}
Until ($TimeNow -ge $TimeEnd)
```

Comment: You have a good idea of what you want to achieve. I'd say go ahead and do it. StackOverflow will be the place where you can ask questions, if you get stuck in the process. And people here are happy to help if you show what you tried and how it is not working.

Comment: I would do some serious searching before you waste time on coding though, from a brief google search seems there are several ways to do this, with code available.

Comment: Why don't you just use SCCM to and enforce a deployment with a deadline? If a reboot is required it will prompt the user every so often until the deadline is met.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Yes there are several ways to do this, but haven't been to locate one with my companies desired results. This script works great to allow users to defer, but at the end of the Do loop, it closes and doesn't force the reboot at $TimeEnd. So we want to start prompting at 07:00, allow them to defer until 13:00, prompt you're out of time and force the shutdown with a cpl min. to save work. I can deploy the script with SCCM to run once a week.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again all! Adding this if statement before the Until gives me my desired result.

$TimeNow = Get-Date
if ($TimeNow -ge $TimeEnd)
{
shutdown -r -f -t 600 -c "You have reached the allotted time for reboot delay. Please save your work and reboot or your computer will automatically reboot in 10 minutes."
}

Thanks to this post https://www.itninja.com/blog/view/reboot-required-toast-notifications-for-windows-machines for the original script. I just modified for my desired results.